# openmp data dependency/ wait for var

Tags: c, openmp

How to solve following problem with OpenMP:

**Edit:** Panni is right, my parallel approach doesn't work, so what's a nice way to do this?

**Situation:**

Function call order:

1. calc();
2. move();

function `calc()` parallelizes a loop via `#pragma omp parallel for` and changes a array containing structs with `x` and `y` values.

function `move()` parallelizes a loop via `#pragma omp for` only and accesses the values changed in `calc()`.

**Question:**

How can I make sure in OpenMP that function `1` has set the values, before I access function `2`?

**More specific:**

```
#include <...>

static b_t *b;

static void calc() {
    #pragma omp parallel for private(j)
    for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            b[i].f.x += some_value;
            b[i].f.y += some_value;
            b[j].f.x -= some_value;
            b[j].f.y -= some_value;
        }
    }        
}

static move() {
    #pragma omp for
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        d.x = b[i].f.x;
        d.y = b[i].f.y;
    }
}

int main() {
    for (i = 0; t < end; t += dt) {
        calc();
        move();
    }
}
```

So, how can I make sure `move()` gets only called after `calc()`? I thought about `#pragma omp task depend(in/out)` but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Why would you use `#pragma omp parallel for` for one but `#pragma omp for` for the other loop?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling the function `calc()` and `move()` in sequential order the `calc()` function will always be executed first.

So the program runs `calc()` waits until it is completed (no matter how many threads are used) and then continues to run `move()`

Comment: Note, too, that as written, there is no parallelism in move!

Answer (score 0):

Panni has said exactly what i want to say.

It sucks I still can't comment.
And I don't want to answer for simply like this.

So I guess you may suffer a performance issue for two reasons.

1. imbalanced workload scheduling on a triangular.
2. cache miss problem if cache can't hold the whole **b**.

move func looks weird to me, so I didn't take it into consideration.